# How to handle your code that later versions of the framework include?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I have to work with an old version of Mono in [Unity](http://unity3d.com) projects. I find myself recreating some classes and extension methods that exist in later versions of .NET. Should I be marking these with an attribute that will make it easy to take them out at a later point, just wait for the inevitable errors, and delete the duplicate code, or take some other approach I'm not familiar with yet? If the attribute route is the way to go, is there already an appropriate attribute created for this kind of thing?

Here's what I'd like:

```
[PresentInDotNET(3.5)]
```

I fill in the version and get alerted when the framework is at that level or higher.

Comment: /* this sucks */ is a comment that any editor can find back easily.  You stop it from sucking by contributing to the project, that's the way they move ahead.  If you don't like to contribute then stop fighting it and use what it supports.

Comment: What does the hypothetical message-producing attribute add, as opposed to the error message you will already get that the type is defined in another assembly? You would have to modify the build chain to recognize this attribute if you want to handle it transparently.

Comment: I either can't or don't know how to recreate some functionality. e.g. I did int.HasFlag instead of Enum.HasFlag because the latter seemed like a ridiculous undertaking. I still want that stuff to be marked for deletion when the framework provides.

Comment: But if you do that, all your existing code would simply cease to compile, forcing you to hand-tweak every single instance. This is a lot of busywork for no gain. If you can't provide drop-in replacements, there is no shame in wrappers.

Comment: The gain is in deleting the useless code, which is in a repo that gets used in all projects, not just projects that referenced the obsolete code before it became obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Split them off to a separate assembly, and change the set of assemblies that make up the final delivery based on the .NET version. You need to rebuild your main assembly to refer to the correct assemblies (depending on whether `Foo` is in `MySystem` or `System`), but as long as you keep namespaces identical, that's all. If you are not even interested in keeping compatibility with older versions, you can simply delete classes from this assembly as they become available.

Alternatively, if the classes/extension methods you are recreating are not interesting (in the sense that you gain nothing by having .NET supply them for you), simply put them in their separate namespace and accept that you are duplicating code already present in newer versions. It doesn't matter a whole lot which assembly gets the job done, after all, as long as it happens.

Whatever you do, try to avoid going the route of `#ifdef`s, runtime discovery, and other conditional code, as this is much harder to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding "// TODO" comments for places like this?  Visual Studio will display these in the Task window and you can get at them pretty easily.